# swapping elements in a for loop returns the same index after swap

Tags: python, for-loop, swap

can someone explain me the loop below:

```
for item in aList[start:end:1]:
  aList[aList.index(item)],aList[aList.index(item)+1] = aList[aList.index(item)],aList[aList.index(item)+1]
```

Let s say aList = [5,2,3,6,1]. the first iteration the index would 0. in the second would be again 0 and after will be increased to 2. Thus it will choose [5,2] and will continue with [2,5] [3,6]....

Why is that and what is the right way to do this?

**UPDATE:** The above is just an example of a specific behavior I wanted to understand. the actual code tries to implement a coctail sort algorithm. 
The actual code is like that

```
if f == 1:
        for d in area[start:end:f]:
            print area,f ,d,area[area.index(d)+1],area.index(d)+1

            if d > area[area.index(d)+1]:
                tmp = area.index(d)
                area[tmp], area[tmp+1] = area[tmp+1],area[tmp]
                area=area
        end -= 1
        f = ~f + 1
    if f == -1:

        for d in area[end:start:f]:
            print area,f,d,area[area.index(d)-1],area.index(d)-1
            if d < area[area.index(d)-1]:
                tmp = area.index(d)
                area[tmp], area[tmp-1] = area[tmp-1], area[tmp]
                area=area

        start += 1
        f = ~f + 1
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to mutate a list while iterating over it

Comment: Although -  `aList[start:end:1]` would make a copy  of the list (if `start = 0` and `end = len(aList)`) -- but in this case `item` would refer to elements in the original list and not the elements in the mutated list. Once I supply those definitions for `start` and `end` and use your example, I get a subscript out of range error. It is mysterious what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As John said, it is a bad idea to mutate a list whilst looping over it. Instead create a copy of the list and change the data in the copy of the list. However it's also unclear what you are trying to achieve so if you specify that there might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into the problem, it's worth noting there are a couple issues with the code as written.

- `start` and `end` aren't defined
- The assignment in the for-loop doesn't actually swap the order

Those things aside, the algorithm fails, because you iterate over every item. I'll go through 2 iterations to show you why that's so.

Let's use your example:
aList = [5,2,3,6,1]

### First iteration:

`item = 5`
`aList.index(5) = 0`
so, we're going to swap `aList[0]` and `aList[1]`
at the end of the iteration, `aList = [2,5,3,6,1]`

### Second iteration:

`item = 2`
Wait, why 2? Because the slice operation creates a new list that we're iterating over, and that list has the original order.

`aList.index(2) = 0`
so, we're going to swap `aList[0]` and `aList[1]`... again.
at the end of the iteration, `aList = [5,2,3,6,1]`... which is the original order.

### And so on

On the third iteration, we'll wind up swapping the 3rd and 4th items. And on the fourth iteration of the loop, we'll swap them again.

You can verify this is the case by adding a print statement to your for-loop: `print aList`.

### So how do you fix it?

You can get around this behavior by iterating over every other item, instead of every item. Try changing the slice stride (step) to 2, instead of 1.

Comment: Your should also suggest the OP to iterate through index rather than item itself, if OP wants to swap every two elements in the list, then the current approach works only if there isn't any duplicates inside the list.

Comment: @john you are right about how it iterates. However the fix doesnt work in my case.